# JSON streaming with Oboe.js, MongoDB and Express.js

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, node.js-stream, jsonstream

I'm experimenting with JSON streaming through HTTP with Oboe.js, MongoDB and Express.js.

The point is to do a query in `MongoDB` (Node.js's mongodb native drive), pipe it (a JavaScript array) to `Express.js` and parse it in the browser with `Oboe.js`.

The benchmarks I did compared `streaming` vs. `blocking` in both the MongoDB query server-side and the JSON parsing in the client-side.

Here is the source code for the two benchmarks. The `first number` is the number of milli-seconds for `1000 queries` of `100 items` (pagination) in a `10 million documents collection` and the `second number` between parenthesis, represents the number of milli-seconds before the very first item in the MongoDB result array is parsed.

The streaming benchmark server-side:

```
// Oboe.js - 20238 (16.887)
// Native - 16703 (16.69)

collection
.find()
.skip(+req.query.offset)
.limit(+req.query.limit)
.stream()
.pipe(JSONStream.stringify())
.pipe(res);
```

The blocking benchmark server-side:

```
// Oboe.js - 17418 (14.267)
// Native - 13706 (13.698)

collection
.find()
.skip(+req.query.offset)
.limit(+req.query.limit)
.toArray(function (e, docs) {
    res.json(docs);
});
```

These results really surprise me because I would have thought that:

1. `Streaming` would be quicker than `blocking` every single time.
2. `Oboe.js` would be quicker to parse the entire JSON array compared to the native `JSON.parse` method.
3. `Oboe.js` would be quicker to parse the first element in the array compared to the native `JSON.parse` method.

Does anyone have an explanation ?
What am I doing wrong ?

Here is the source-code for the two client-side benchmarks too.

The streaming benchmark client-side:

```
var limit = 100;
var max = 1000;

var oboeFirstTimes = [];
var oboeStart = Date.now();

function paginate (i, offset, limit) {
    if (i === max) {
        console.log('> OBOE.js time:', (Date.now() - oboeStart));
        console.log('> OBOE.js avg. first time:', (
            oboeFirstTimes.reduce(function (total, time) {
                return total + time;
            }, 0) / max
        ));
        return true;
    }

    var parseStart = Date.now();
    var first = true;
    oboe('/api/spdy-stream?offset=' + offset + '&limit=' + limit)
    .node('![*]', function () {
        if (first) {
            first = false;
            oboeFirstTimes.push(Date.now() - parseStart);
        }
    })
    .done(function () {
        paginate(i + 1, offset + limit, limit);
    });
}

paginate(0, 0, limit);
```

The blocking benchmark client-side:

```
var limit = 100;
var max = 1000;

var nativeFirstTimes = [];
var nativeStart = Date.now();

function paginate (i, offset, limit) {
    if (i === max) {
        console.log('> NATIVE time:', (Date.now() - nativeStart));
        console.log('> NATIVE avg. first time:', (
            nativeFirstTimes.reduce(function (total, time) {
                return total + time;
            }, 0) / max
        ));
        return true;
    }

    var parseStart = Date.now();
    var first = true;

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', '/api/spdy-stream?offset=' + offset + '&limit=' + limit, true);

    req.onload = function () {
        var json = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
        json.forEach(function () {
            if (first) {
                first = false;
                nativeFirstTimes.push(Date.now() - parseStart);
            }
        });
        paginate(i + 1, offset + limit, limit);
    };

    req.send();
}

paginate(0, 0, limit);
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

I found those comments in Oboe doc at the end of the "Why Oboe?" section:

*Because it is a pure Javascript parser, Oboe.js requires more CPU time than JSON.parse. Oboe.js works marginally more slowly for small messages that load very quickly but for most real-world cases using i/o effectively beats optimising CPU time.
SAX parsers require less memory than Oboe’s pattern-based parsing model because they do not build up a parse tree. See Oboe.js vs SAX vs DOM.
If in doubt, benchmark, but don’t forget to use the real internet, including mobile, and think about perceptual performance.*